# UART Transmit and receive data does not start (Vivado)

Tags: verilog, uart, vivado

I can't figure out why is it that when I set the clock frequency from 50MHz to 100MHz, by changing the `clk` period to 5 in the testbench, my output transmit and receive data stays at 0. Can anyone enlighten me on this? I need my clock frequency to be **100MHz**. Your help will be much appreciated.

Testbench

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
 
 
module uart_tx_test();
parameter       periodCLK_2     = 5;

parameter       perioddump      = 10;
parameter       delay           = 1;
parameter       delay_in        = 2;

reg           CLK_TB  = 0       ;
reg           RSTN           ;
reg [7:0] data = 0;
reg clk = 0;
reg enable = 0;

wire tx_busy;
wire rdy;
wire [7:0] rxdata;

wire loopback;
reg rdy_clr = 0;

uart test_uart(.din(data),
           .wr_en(enable),
           .clk_50m(clk),
           .tx(loopback),
           .tx_busy(tx_busy),
           .rx(loopback),
           .rdy(rdy),
           .rdy_clr(rdy_clr),
           .dout(rxdata));

initial begin
    // $dumpfile("uart.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, uart_tx_test);
    enable <= 1'b1;
    #2 enable <= 1'b0;
end

always begin
    #5 clk = ~clk; //I set period to 5; period was 1 previously.
end 

always @(posedge rdy) begin
    #2 rdy_clr <= 1;
    #2 rdy_clr <= 0;
    if (rxdata != data) begin
        $display("FAIL: rx data %x does not match tx %x", rxdata, data);
        $finish;
    end else begin
        if (rxdata == 8'hff) begin
            $display("SUCCESS: all bytes verified");
            $finish;
        end
        data <= data + 1'b1;
        enable <= 1'b1;
        #2 enable <= 1'b0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Design Sources

```
module uart(
    input wire [7:0] din,
    input wire wr_en,
    input wire clk_50m,
    output wire tx,
    output wire tx_busy,

    input wire rx,
    input wire rdy_clr,
    output wire rdy,
    output wire [7:0] dout
);

wire rxclk_en, txclk_en;

baud_rate_gen uart_baud(
    .clk_50m(clk_50m),
    .rxclk_en(rxclk_en),
    .txclk_en(txclk_en)
);

transmitter uart_tx(
    .tx(tx),
    .din(din),
    .clk_50m(clk_50m),
    .clken(txclk_en),
    .wr_en(wr_en),
    .tx_busy(tx_busy)
);

receiver uart_rx(
    .rx(rx),
    .data(dout),
    .clk_50m(clk_50m),
    .clken(rxclk_en),
    .rdy(rdy),
    .rdy_clr(rdy_clr)
);

endmodule
/*
 * Hacky baud rate generator to divide a 50MHz clock into a 9600 baud
 * rx/tx pair where the rx clcken oversamples by 16x.
 */
module baud_rate_gen(input wire clk_50m,
             output wire rxclk_en,
             output wire txclk_en);

parameter RX_ACC_MAX = 100000000 / (9600 * 16);
parameter TX_ACC_MAX = 100000000 / 9600;
parameter RX_ACC_WIDTH = $clog2(RX_ACC_MAX);
parameter TX_ACC_WIDTH = $clog2(TX_ACC_MAX);
reg [RX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0] rx_acc = 0;
reg [TX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0] tx_acc = 0;

assign rxclk_en = (rx_acc == 5'd0);
assign txclk_en = (tx_acc == 9'd0);

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
    if (rx_acc == RX_ACC_MAX[RX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0])
        rx_acc <= 0;
    else
        rx_acc <= rx_acc + 5'b1;
end

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
    if (tx_acc == TX_ACC_MAX[TX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0])
        tx_acc <= 0;
    else
        tx_acc <= tx_acc + 9'b1;
end

endmodule
module transmitter(
    input wire [7:0] din,
    input wire wr_en,
    input wire clk_50m,
    input wire clken,
    output reg tx,
    output wire tx_busy
);

initial begin
     tx = 1'b1;
end

parameter STATE_IDLE    = 2'b00;
parameter STATE_START   = 2'b01;
parameter STATE_DATA    = 2'b10;
parameter STATE_STOP    = 2'b11;

reg [7:0] data = 8'h00;
reg [2:0] bitpos = 3'h0;
reg [1:0] state = STATE_IDLE;

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
    case (state)
    STATE_IDLE: begin
        if (wr_en) begin
            state <= STATE_START;
            data <= din;
            bitpos <= 3'h0;
        end
    end
    STATE_START: begin
        if (clken) begin
            tx <= 1'b0;
            state <= STATE_DATA;
        end
    end
    STATE_DATA: begin
        if (clken) begin
            if (bitpos == 3'h7)
                state <= STATE_STOP;
            else
                bitpos <= bitpos + 3'h1;
            tx <= data[bitpos];
        end
    end
    STATE_STOP: begin
        if (clken) begin
            tx <= 1'b1;
            state <= STATE_IDLE;
        end
    end
    default: begin
        tx <= 1'b1;
        state <= STATE_IDLE;
    end
    endcase
end

assign tx_busy = (state != STATE_IDLE);

endmodule
module receiver(
    input wire rx,
    input wire rdy_clr,
    input wire clk_50m,
    input wire clken,
    output reg rdy,
    output reg [7:0] data
);

initial begin
    rdy = 0;
    data = 8'b0;
end

parameter RX_STATE_START    = 2'b00;
parameter RX_STATE_DATA     = 2'b01;
parameter RX_STATE_STOP     = 2'b10;

reg [1:0] state = RX_STATE_START;
reg [3:0] sample = 0;
reg [3:0] bitpos = 0;
reg [7:0] scratch = 8'b0;

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
    if (rdy_clr)
        rdy <= 0;

    if (clken) begin
        case (state)
        RX_STATE_START: begin
            /*
            * Start counting from the first low sample, once we've
            * sampled a full bit, start collecting data bits.
            */
            if (!rx || sample != 0)
                sample <= sample + 4'b1;

            if (sample == 15) begin
                state <= RX_STATE_DATA;
                bitpos <= 0;
                sample <= 0;
                scratch <= 0;
            end
        end
        RX_STATE_DATA: begin
            sample <= sample + 4'b1;
            if (sample == 4'h8) begin
                scratch[bitpos[2:0]] <= rx;
                bitpos <= bitpos + 4'b1;
            end
            if (bitpos == 8 && sample == 15)
                state <= RX_STATE_STOP;
        end
        RX_STATE_STOP: begin
            /*
             * The baud clock may not be running at exactly the
             * same rate as the transmitter.  If we thing that
             * we're at least half way into the stop bit, allow
             * transition into handling the next start bit.
             */
            if (sample == 15 || (sample >= 8 && !rx)) begin
                state <= RX_STATE_START;
                data <= scratch;
                rdy <= 1'b1;
                sample <= 0;
            end else begin
                sample <= sample + 4'b1;
            end
        end
        default: begin
            state <= RX_STATE_START;
        end
        endcase
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Hi @toolic, thanks for the response. The variable data[7:0] should be incrementing bytes. Try period == 1 -> ```#1 clk = ~clk;```. It will output the values in data[7:0] in the simulation. The simulation should stop once it displays "Success all bytes verified is displayed.", which means all bytes are from 0 to ff are "transferred"

Comment: @toolic Doing ```#1 clk = ~clk``` would generate 50Mhz clock frequency. If I change it back to ```#5 clk = ~clk``` which is what I want, because it means that the clock frequency is now 100Mhz, the data[7:0] would stay at 0... no matter how long the simulation runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scale all your other delays accordingly. Change all your `#2` to `#10`, then you will see the `SUCCESS: all bytes verified` message.

With your original clock delay of `#1`, your other input signal pulses (`enable` and `rdy_clr`) were wide enough for your `uart` design module to sample properly.  For example, on the 1st posedge of `clk`, your design properly sampled the `enable` input as 1, which started the TX state machine.

You increased the clock period by a factor of 5 when you changed the delay from `#1` to `#5`.  However, your `enable` pulse stayed the same width as before, which means that the design sampled `enable` as 0, not 1.  So your TX state machine stayed in the IDLE state.  By changing the `enable` delay from `#2` to `#10`, you are able to properly sample `enable` as 1.

You can easily prove this to yourself by dumping a VCD file, and viewing the waveforms inside the design.

---

You could replace the numeric delays with a `parameter` to make it easier to change to different frequencies.

---

Note: You stated the `clk` delay was originally `#1`.  This gives the `clk` signal a period of 2ns, which is **500**MHz, not 50MHz.